# Confusion about the definition of a formal Legendrian isotopy

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry, legendrian-submanifolds

We say two Legendrian embeddings $f_0,f_1:L^n\rightarrow (Y^{2n+1},\xi)$ are formally isotopic if there is a smooth isotopy $f_t$ connecting $f_0$ and $f_1$ and a bundle monomorphism $F_t^s:TL\rightarrow TY$ such that $F_t^0=df_t, F_0^s=df_0, F_1^s=df_1$ and $F_t^1$ is a Lagrangian monomorphism.

My question is: Does $F_t^s$ have to cover $f_t$?

Some literatures requires $F_t^s$ to cover $f_t$. However, when I read the book of Cieliebak and Eliashberg: "From Stein to Weinstein and Back: Symplectic geometry of affine complex manifolds", I realized that their formal isotopy $(f_t,F_t^s)$ doesn't cover $f_t$. For example, in the theorem 7.16 (p.139), they proved any formal legendrian embedding is formally isotopic to a genuine legendrian. In this proof, they first construct a Legendrian regular homotopy, and upgrade this to a smooth isotopy and the differential of the regular homotopy plays a role of a path of Lagrangian monomorphisms, which clearly doesn't cover $f_t$.

Are they just equivalent definitions? Or are there any differences between them?

Comment: Yes, $F_t^s$ must cover $f_t$.